# Issues getting validation working with dynamically generating form inputs?

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have some basic form/input html that works (including validation) if explicitly written as follows:

```
<form name="forms.create" novalidate>
    <div class="si-container">
        <div class="si-input-container">
            <input class="si-input" name="someNum" placeholder="Enter a number" ng-model="formdata.number" type="number" min="40"/>
        </div>
        <div class="si-error">
            <div ng-show="forms.create.someNum.$error.min">Error! Value must be > 40.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now what I want to do is create a directive that allows me to write the html below, but result in the html above:

```
<form name="forms.create" novalidate>
    <div special-input name="someNum" placeholder="Enter a number" type="number" ng-model="formdata.number">
        <div error-type="min" error-value="40">Error! Value must be > 40.</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My attempt at the `special-input` directive (simplified) is as follows:

```
.directive('specialInput', [function(){
    return {
        compile: function(elem, attrs){

            var input = angular.element('<input class="si-input"/>');

            input.attr('placeholder', attrs.placeholder);
            input.attr('type', attrs.type);
            input.attr('name', attrs.name);
            input.attr('ng-model', attrs.ngModel);

            var errorCont = angular.element('<div class="si-error"></div>');

            var errors = elem.children();
            angular.forEach(errors, function(error){
                var err = angular.element(error);
                var type = err.attr('error-type');
                var value = err.attr('error-value');
                input.attr(type, value);

                var formName = elem.parent().attr('name');
                errorCont.append('<div ng-show="' + formName + '.' + attrs.name + '.$error.' + type + '">' + err.html() + '</div>');
            });

            var cont = angular.element('<div class="si-container"></div>');
            cont.append('<div class="si-floating-label">' + attrs.placeholder + '</div>');
            cont.append('<div class="si-input-container">' + input[0].outerHTML + '</div>');
            cont.append('<div class="si-underline"></div>');  
            cont.append(errorCont);              

            elem.replaceWith(cont[0].outerHTML);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Now the resultant html using the directive above looks about right. If I put `{{formdata.number}}` below the form the value changes as expected. The problem is that now the validation never shows.

For example, if I put the value `5` in the input and inspect the form object, I get weird results. `$dirty` is set to true for `form`, but not for `form.someNum`. If I put `55` in the input, `$dirty` is still set to false for `form.someNum`, but `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` both show 55.

Any ideas or suggestions? Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTpMM/)** to help with any testing. 
*If you put 50 in the input box you should see the value below, but put 5 and the error does not appear*

---

*UPDATE*

I have managed to get it working by moving the dom changes into the link function instead of the compile function, and adding this:

```
elem.replaceWith(cont);
$compile(cont)(scope);
```

I am still puzzled though, as to why this works, while altering the dom in the exact same way in the compile function doesn't work. Is anyone able to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the original `ng-model` is still get compiled even the original DOM has already been replaced by the new one in your compile function.

The `ng-model` directive will register itself to a parent form in its postLink function. Due to the fact that the postLink function will be executed in reverse (child's before parent's), the new `ng-model` will do the registration first, thus it will be overridden by the one from the original `ng-model` eventually.

To avoid this problem, you could change the original `ng-model` to another name such as `my-model`, then rename it to `ng-model` later in your compile function.

**Example jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Wr3cJ/1/

Hope this helps.